# Changing x-axis values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe called Finalcombined which includes quarter (2004 Q1 until 2013 Q4) and Labourproductivity.

```
quarter LabourProductivity
==========================
2004 Q1    96.6
2004 Q2    96.9
2004 Q3    96.9
2004 Q4    97.1
2005 Q1    97.6
```

---

```
labourproductivitygraph <- ggplot(data=Finalcombined, aes(x=quarter, y=LabourProductivity))+geom_line(colour="black", size=0.5) +
  labs(x="Time[Quarter]", y=("Labour Productivity")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white", size=0.50),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "white", size=0.16)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16), axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) +
  geom_point(colour="black", size=2, shape=16) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=TRUE, col="blue", size=0.70, alpha=0.40, aes(group=1)) 
labourproductivitygraph
```

After running this code I got the following error:

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the data you use, because the above line "quarter...97.6" isn't exactly clear.

Comment: Sorry I am new to R and this platform and not entirely sure how to format my data so it appears correctly. My variable quarter exists of 2004 Q1, 2004 Q2, 2004 Q3, 2004 Q4, 2005 Q5 and so on until 2013 Q4 (from top to bottom) and my variable LabourProductivity exists of 96.6, 96.9, 96.9, 97.1, 97.6 and so on (from top to bottom). Hope this clarifies more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your X variable is not in a format that ggplot recognizes as continuous. Because it sees "Q1 2004", for instance, as a string, the X variable is interpreted as a factor. This explains the error you're getting - it looks to ggplot like you're trying to do statistics on a bunch of groups that only have one value, which is generally not something that people intend to do.

So to fix this, you need to convert the X variable to something that ggplot recognizes as continuous. This could either be a date or a series of numbers. Assuming you have data for every quarter, the simplest thing to do is probably to use a placeholder sequence that goes from 1 to the length of the dataframe. You can use this sequence as your X variable, and just use the quarter variable to label ticks along the X axis. Here's some sample code:

```
Finalcombined$sequence <- c(1:length(Finalcombined$quarter))
labourproductivitygraph <- ggplot(data=Finalcombined, aes(x=sequence, y=LabourProductivity))+geom_line(colour="black", size=0.5) + labs(x="Time[Quarter]", y=("Labour Productivity")) + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white", size=0.50), panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "white", size=0.16)) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16), axis.title=element_text(size=16,face="bold")) + geom_point(colour="black", size=2, shape=16) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=TRUE, col="blue", size=0.70, alpha=0.40) + scale_x_continuous(labels=quarter)
labourproductivitygraph
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Didn't work and got the following error: Error in structure(list(call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : 
  object 'quarter' not found
> labourproductivitygraph
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = function (nvec)  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 40

Comment: Oh, oops, I forgot to specify a column of the data frame to take the length of. I edited the code to fix that. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't work! Got the following error message: Error in labs(x = "Time[Quarter]", y = ("Labour Productivity")) + theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white",  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Hmm, looks like some whitespace got inserted into the call at weird places due to my formatting. That's the only explanation I can come up with for that error. I simplified the formatting. Does this work? If not, could you describe the types of the columns of your dataframe?

Comment: I have just added group=1 in aes() and it worked!! Only thing i have left to do is drooping a few of the values of the x axis meaning only having left (2004 Q1, 2005 Q1, 2006 Q1 and so on) Do you know how I would go about that? Thank you so much!